# DatabaseError: ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run the following query on a postgres database, it works well. But on an oracle database it sends error

> ORA-01722: invalid number

This query on oracle had been working till one week ago, and during this week it generates an error.

The general syntax is as below:

```
SELECT MIN(idd) FROM
(SELECT CAST(id AS INTEGER) idd
 FROM prev_table) new_table
```

Without the `MIN` function, it works.

The problem occurs when I use `MIN()` to get the minimum id.

In this prev_table, id column is defined as varchar, and I want to convert them to integer and then get minimum.

Comment: Though I know nothing on Oracle (your (mis)use of the tag [[tag:tsql]] brought me here), I suspect *someone* has inserted a value that (as the error says) is an **invalid number** (`'12n4'` for example). The real problem is that you are using a `varchar` column for a value you want to be numerical it seems.

Comment: Use `select distinct id from prev_table where validate_conversion(id as integer) = 0` to find out invalid numbers. `min` returns an error because it forces the engine to process all the rows, while plain `select` returns only a few arbitrary rows of a table.

Comment: In real query, I filtered rows to get just numeral data.

Comment: @SRoshan You may think that you've done, but Oracle still doesn't know how to convert the data to a number. You cannot just force it to do a conversion, but to "explain" how to do it. Please provide reproducible example: DDL for a table and `insert` statement to fill it with the data that cannot be converted to number. Otherwise the question is not answerable

Comment: @SRoshan - you're assuming your filter is applied before any conversion is done, but that's up to the optimiser - and as you're getting the error, it isn't doing what you expected/hoped. You need to handle it in a robust way that doesn't rely on the whims of the optimiser...

Comment: To make problem clearer, I run this code on a column with no non-integer data, and it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not store numbers as text.

From Oracle 12.2, you can use `TO_NUMBER(... DEFAULT ... ON CONVERSION ERROR)`:

```sql
SELECT MIN(TO_NUMBER(id DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR)) AS min_id
FROM   prev_table
WHERE  TO_NUMBER(id DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) IS NOT NULL;
```

or `VALIDATE_CONVERSION`:

```sql
SELECT MIN(TO_NUMBER(id)) AS min_id
FROM   prev_table
WHERE  VALIDATE_CONVERSION(id AS INTEGER) = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE prev_table (id) AS
SELECT 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3e2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '999.9' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '+420' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3e4e' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| MIN_ID |
| --- |
| 300 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LDjtWGnS)

Comment: There may also be NLS issues depending on the defaults, so the above statements may miss valid number stored inapropriately: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NTmxtbrx).